Extracting content from an URl is getting none
import requests
from main_content_extractor import MainContentExtractor

url = "https://testing.nbnhchurch.org/"

response = requests.get(url)

response.encoding = 'utf-8'

content = response.text

extracted_html = MainContentExtractor.extract(content)

extracted_markdown = MainContentExtractor.extract(content, output_format="markdown") 

print("Extracted content:",extracted_markdown)

This is my code to extract content from web page through URL. But I am getting following error for some of the URLs
WARNING:trafilatura.core:discarding data: None
WARNING:trafilatura.core:discarding data: None
Extracted content: None

I wanted to extract main content from a website. For some cases, it is not working as expected. I am not getting the error that I have got.

Some URLs could be dynamic content. Requests doesn't run Javascript, so you'd need to get the content differently, such as using selenium

What is MainContentExtractor?

Use View Source in a browser to see the HTML code that you're scraping from. Does it include the information that MainContentExtractor() looks for?
